# The "suggested edit" preview is confusing

Tags: support, review, markdown-preview

I was reviewing [a suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/127611), and I noticed it was changing the code.

[image]

I then used the other preview, and this is what I have seen.

[image: screenshot]

Was `\only` changed with `\only<2->`? Which of the two previews I can trust?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the reason you can see the markdown view if the rendered view is confusing. The `<2->` doesn't show up in the rendered before view because it's unescaped, so the browser reads it as a tag. It shows up in the after view because the edit made it part of a code block. The rendered view is generally easier to understand, but the markdown view lets you see exactly what was changed in the post source